# Find an orthonormal basis $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$V=${$\left( (x_1,\ldots x_{5}\right) \in \mathbb{R} ^{5}:x_1+2x_2-3x_3=0, x_1+x_3+x_5=0$}.

Find an orthonormal basis $V$

**How can I find $x_1,...,x_5$?** Can you help?

Comment: I'd suggest breaking the problem down into two parts: (1) find a basis, and then (2) make that basis orthonormal.  How far can you get on (1)?

Comment: Okey. So, what are the $x_1...x_5$?

Comment: I don't follow.  They're placeholders -- you want to find a basis for the space of vectors $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\rangle$ such that these two equations are satisfied.

Comment: @Kahler do you understand set builder notation? For instance, do you understand that $$\{x\in \Bbb R : x^2=9\} = \{-3,3\}?$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $V$ is the nullspace of the matrix
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
We can compute a basis for $V$ by row-reducing $A$. This gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, we see that $A\vec x=\vec 0$ if and only if 
$$
\vec x=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-x_3-x_5 \\
2\,x_3+\frac{1}{2}\,x_5 \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{array}\right]
=
x_3
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-1\\2\\1\\0\\0
\end{array}\right]+
x_4
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0\\0\\0\\1\\0
\end{array}\right]+
x_5
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-1\\\frac{1}{2}\\0\\0\\1
\end{array}\right]
$$
From here, it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
\vec v_1 &=\left[\begin{array}{r}
-1\\2\\1\\0\\0
\end{array}\right] &
\vec v_2 &=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0\\0\\0\\1\\0
\end{array}\right]&
\vec v_3 &=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-1\\\frac{1}{2}\\0\\0\\1
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
form a basis of $V$.

Is this an orthonormal basis? If so, then we are done. If not, then we can apply the [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to this basis to produce an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0):

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is obvious.

since $x_1$ and $x_3$ are in both equations, try setting $x_1 = 0$ and $x_3 = 1$ and solving for $x_2, x_5$

That will give you a second vector in the basis.

And then set $x_1 = 1$ and $x_3 = 0$ and solve for $x_2$ and $x_5$

Now you have a basis.

How do you make it ortho-normal?

Graham-Schmidt

$v_1$ is already normal.  leave it alone.

find $v_1\cdot v_2$ it will be 0 unless you have screwed things up.  Great, v_2 is ortogonal to $v_1.$

Normalize $v_2.$  That is find $u_2 = \frac {v_2}{\|v_2\|}$

next find $v_1\cdot v_3$ should be 0.

and now the tricky part.

find $u_2\cdot v_3$ not $0$?

find $u_3 = \frac {v_3 - (u_2\cdot v_3)u_2}{\|v_3 - (u_2\cdot v_3)u_2\|}.$